# How to write this code in powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How to write this code in powershell ?

```
for /D %%i in (C:\Year_2015\*) do pushd .&cls .&cd "%%i"&call c:\Teste\Teste2\file.bat %%i&popd .&cls
```

I do not know where to start ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\Year_2015'
$loc=Get-Location
$dirs | ForEach-Object {
  Clear-Host
  Set-Location -Path $PSItem.FullName
  C:\Teste\Teste2\file.bat $PSItem.FullName
  Set-Location -Path $loc.Path
  Clear-Host
}
```

Suggestions for you:

1. Start with Bing/Google, look for 'Powershell tutorial'.
2. Play around within Windows by loading up the Powershell ISE (Start->[search] Windows Powershell ISE)
3. Make liberal use of the:

   a. Get-Help
4. Some things that should help you get started...

   a. Get-Help Get-ChildItem

   b. Get-Help ForEach-Object

Comment: No need to save/restore the original location. Just do `foreach ($dir in (Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\Year_2015')) { Clear-Host; Push-Location $dir.FullName; C:\Teste\Teste2\file.bat $dir.FullName; Pop-Location; Clear-Host }`

Comment: "Ok... but... did not work." doesn't seem like a PowerShell error code that I am familiar with, or that I would be able to diagnose for you in any meaningful way. Bing or Google is likely your best bet now - just paste any error messages you get back from my script into the search field and you should have a good place to start sorting things out for yourself.

Comment: @Jones Edits are for fixing problems with posts. Please don't suggest edits to attach comments or respond to the poster.